# Fast method of "marking up" URL's and hash tags in text

Tags: java, algorithm, text-processing

I need to process large amounts of messages, to do two basic things, convert URL's and hashtags into links. There are many ways I could go about doing this, but what would be the most CPU and memory efficient way in java? For example:

```
This is some #text with for http://mysite.com/
```

becomes:

```
This is some <a href="">#text</a> for <a href="">http://mysite.com/</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

My first idea were two calls to [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), one for tags, one for links. The code will be readable and quite fast.

My second idea is something faster, but more ugly. Something that does everything in one pass. General idea:

```
final String message = "This is some #text with for http://mysite.com/";
for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++)
{
    if (message[i] == '#')
    {
        // mark a hashtag
    }
    else if (i < message.length - 6 && (message[i] == 'h' || message[i + 1] == 't' || message[i + 2] == 't' || message[i + 3] == 'p' || message[i + 4] == ':' || message[i + 5] == '/' || message[i + 6] == '/'))
    {
        // mark a link
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I like this. And is possibly faster due to it not depending on regular expressions. I'll test it against the more obvious regular expression solution and see which is faster. It looks as if this option might result in less garbage collection as well.